# Javascript: add to static URL based on user input & add #xyz to it

Tags: javascript, html

Was wondering if someone can point me on the right direction: I am trying to create an experience where there is a static URL with an input box, but when a user inputs anything, that URL changes and also adds '#xyz'.

Static URL: google.com
user adds "123" to the input box and clicks 'proceed'
New tab opens with google.com/123#xyz

Here is the fiddle that I am working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sxz4R/535/

```
<input type="text" id="askquestion" placeholder="ask your question" />
<a class="target" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Proceed</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#askquestion').change(function() {
      var newurl = $('#askquestion').val();
      $('a.target').attr('href', newurl + '#123');
    });
});
```

Right now the two issues: it doesn't take the google.com URL & it adds '/#' instead of '#'

Thanks for any insights
-Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sxz4R/537/

You were overwriting href of `a.target`, all you need to do is compose your URL correctly.

Also notice that I added a trailing slash to `http://www.google.com/` in the original `proceed` link

Comment: appreciate this, just had a small q (and this might just be jsfiddle) but if I use your solution, it works perfectly. However, when I go back and try to enter a new entry, it reverts back to the first variable that is saved. Any idea how to make it use the latest input? (once I refresh the jsfiddle, it works fine, but if you try to input a few times and click proceed, the URL is the same from the first one)

Comment: Ah, this is because it's using whatever is in the `href` attribute and adding to that.  You could just have the base URL declared in the JS like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Sxz4R/544/.  This way, it will always start w/ the base url as `http://www.google.com/`

Comment: that did the trick, thanks a lot mate, really appreciate your kind and quick help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my improved version. Note that I correctly deal with slashes, even in the user input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $a = $('a.target'),
    baseUrl = $a.attr('href').replace(/\/+$/, ''); // remove any trailing slash
  $('#askquestion').on('change input', function() {
    var newurl = $(this).val();
    // add a leading slash after removing any that might be there already
    newurl = '/' + newurl.replace(/^\/+/, '');
    $a.attr('href', baseUrl + newurl + '#123');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="askquestion" placeholder="ask your question" />
<a class="target" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Proceed</a>
```